# Error on mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to mvn clean install and this is the error massage I'm getting :-

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils

I read on some other solutions and I got and advice to add the below tags on my pom.xml but I still get the same error. Any idea what to do?

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ir.codepress.MainApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-September/009427.html Are you using java9 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm on java version "9-ea"

Comment: That's probably the issue, see guice bugtracker on github.

Comment: ...or should I just go back to 8 to save myself ?

Comment: Which version of maven-jar-plugin are you using? Please post the full log output...in particular if you are on JDK 9 ...which version of JDK 9 are you using?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: I'm on java version "9-ea"